# Erro [NullReferenceException] - Unity em C#

Tags: c#

Meu código não está dando certo, ocasionando o seguinte erro:

> NullReferenceException

O objetivo é conseguir pular, mas só consigo andar:

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
public float Speed;
private Rigidbody2D rig;
public float JumpForce;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
Move();
Jump();
}

void Move()
{
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
}

void Jump()
{
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
rig.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Olá Erick, seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Sugiro **editar** sua pergunta e acrescentar os critérios, de [mre], vale muito apena dar uma olhada, para assim, poder elaborar uma boa pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

NullReferenceException significa que você está tentando fazer algo com um objeto que não foi inicializado.

No caso você define um objeto do tipo Rigidbody2D

```
private Rigidbody2D rig;
```

**Mas em nenhum lugar você cria uma instância para esse objeto.** Algo do tipo:

```
rig = new Rigidbody2D()
```

Então quando você faz:

```
rig.(QUALQUER_COISA)
```

Você vai receber um NullReferenceException